# Calling eventRender After eventSource available

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3, fullcalendar-2

I need to call eventRender when eventSource available,

```
$(function() {

  function getEventSource () {
    var ev;
    setTimeout(function () {
      ev = [
                {
                    title  : 'event00',
                    start  : '2018-12-10',
                    imageUrl: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0110/6032/files/0000-03_m.jpg?7389502659783226065'
                },
                {
                    title  : 'event01',
                    start  : '2018-12-12',
                    imageUrl: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0110/6032/files/0000-03_m.jpg?7389502659783226065'
                }
            ];
      return ev;

    }, 1000);
  }

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',

    header: {
      center: 'addEventButton'
    },

    events: getEventSource(),
    eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
                    if (event.imageUrl) {
                        eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageUrl +"' width='100%' height='150'>");
                    }
                }


  });

});
```

My initial problem is i am setting eventSource dynamically, like this `this.$elem.fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);`

And once events available, need to call eventRender to set events on calendar.

Is it possible to call eventRender when eventSource available (asynchronously) ?

Comment: "My initial problem is i am setting eventSource dynamically, like this this.$elem.fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);" ...but you never run this code in the example above? It's not clear where or when you call that code, or what the content of `events` is when you do. Also, in the example code, your getEventSource() function makes no sense. It doesn't return a value to the calendar. If you're trying to mock an AJAX call, that's the wrong way to go about it. Use Promises and read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: Or just use a real endpoint such as http://myjson.com/ where you can paste your static JSON, and make a real-life asynchronous AJAX call to it. Then when you finally connect it to your real server you don't have to change any code except for the URL.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Tried promises and it worked !!

Comment: Tested with both approaches addEventSource and events, and worked fine
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BGegzg?editors=0010

Comment: Ok great. But BTW your code pen just shows exactly what is in your example above, and it doesn't work, it never adds the events, because the getEventSource() doesn't return any data. So if you have a fixed version, you should link to that instead, thanks.